# Create custom ObjectContext for DBContext to implement custom logic in CreateObject<T>()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a possbility to use the simple new DbContext and implement a custom ObjectContext to be able to override the Objectcontext.CreateObject() method?

I need this to be able to initialize the entity before the properties are set.

Comment: `Objectcontext.CreateObject()` is not used by EF internally, so overriding it for this purpose is useless. Why don't you initialize objects in their constructor?

Comment: The entities (POCOS) I use are also used with another (self-implemented) ORM. We're about to implement EF as an new way to access data. But this will be a long-running process.

Within the constructor the "DataState" of this entities is set to "created". All entities which are loaded from DB get their data state of "Loaded". Now i want to set the data state to "Loading" during the materialization to disable any validation and other logic.

Is there any other option to detect if this entity is currently materialized? Or is there an option to set a property by EF which is not loaded from DB?

Comment: You can only hook into the `ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` event, which runs *after* an object has been constructed. A DbContext is a wrapper around an ObjectContext.

Comment: I know about this event. But it's fired after all properties has been set. This is to late.

Is there a option to map a property as read only from a calculated field? So I can set my DataState property by the generated sql?
E.g. :
Me.Property(Function(t) t.DataState).HasColumnName("1 As DataState").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)

Comment: But then it should also be a computed column in the database. I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: Is there a option to change the mapping in EF 6.1 (beta)? Is there any documentation yet?